# Why can't I use the front view?

Tags: modeling

I try modeling today but the views don't work how I can resolve that?

[image: why I cant use the front view]

Comment: Is this the same with shortcuts?

Comment: yes, i press the numbers and nothing

Comment: Actually this error might be something unknown! I recommend you to use Blender latest build that is 2.81 :)